# HAproxy - How to forward traffic to backend by a matching header?

Tags: header, load-balancing, haproxy

E.g. the header contains: `X-DEMO-HOST-VERSION: test` - how do i  need to setup the haproxy config to forward to a specific backend? Can this be done within the backend or in the frontend?

Regarding to the documentation i'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

You need a check header (hdr in haproxy) value via ACL. Try it:

```
frontend header_front
    bind *:80
    mode http
    option forwardfor if-none
    acl demo_host_version hdr(X-DEMO-HOST-VERSION) -i test
    use_backend test_backend if demo_host_version
    default_backend prod_backend

backend test_backend
    ...

backend prod_backend
    ...
```

Test for you header:

```
    acl demo_host_version hdr(X-DEMO-HOST-VERSION) -i test
    use_backend test_backend if demo_host_version
```

The logic:
`IF` `X-DEMO-HOST-VERSION=test` use test_backend `ELSE` use prod_backend

---

UPD:
If u need acl for path in URL (`example.com/test/`):

```
    acl demo_host_path path_beg /test/
    use_backend test_backend if demo_host_path
```

If u need use a two ACL in if statement use it:

```
    acl demo_host_version hdr(X-DEMO-HOST-VERSION) -i test
    acl demo_host_path path_beg /test/
    use_backend test_backend if demo_host_path demo_host_version
```

---

UPD for check URL:

Subdomain check. If u domain `test.example.com` or `test.abc.com`, try it:

```
acl host_sub_domain hdr_beg(host) -i test
```

For full domain check, eg `test.example.com`, try it:

```
acl host_full_domain hdr(host) -i test.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I got it to work on our SSL frontend. But is there a way to specify a given URL? As far as i understood i can use every URL defined in HAproxys map file or the address of the load balancer itself. For me that is a little bit unsure. Is there a way?

Comment: @mrpizzamccony ok, check update in my post, maybe this is what you need

Comment: is there a way not using a path/URI but a URL? If i would using a path from the beginning i wouldn't need the header request anymore, because when a given path will be executed than it points to the right backend. Using a special header AND a URI is maybe a little bit to much.

Comment: @mrpizzamccony check the update, i added acl for URL.

Comment: thank you very much! I've got it to work using `use_backend test_backend if host_full_domain demo_host_version`. You really made my day! One last question: Does the lookup into every header and comparing it with the full domain has a huge performance impact?

Comment: @mrpizzamccony u are welcome. no, it is a normal practice to use rules and acl in configurations.
most likely you will be able to get problems with linux performance and system limit, but not with haproxy.

Comment: now i'm facing the problem that test.example.com/somepath is still pointing to the experimental backend using that header. Is there also a possibility to just match test.example.com? I mean when test.example.com/somepath will be quried using the experimental header, it should point to another backend.